# jsf 2.0 we used text/html but it is displaying plain for javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

i am using mail1.4.3 jar in my jsf2.0 application and i am trying to send email on requesting new user , if we send mail the mail content is displaying plain eventhough i am using text/html for mails and my code is

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

```
     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));
     StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
        bld.append("<h2>");
        bld.append("New User Request");
        bld.append(" for <FONT style='color:#4649FE;'> " + "TALON");
        bld.append("</FONT></h2><br/>");
        bld.append("<b>Requested By :");
        bld.append("<FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>" + "Y.Sanjeeva Reddygggggggggg"
                + "</FONT></b><br/>");
        bld.append("<b>Requested on :");
        Date dt = new Date();
        Calendar cel = new GregorianCalendar();
        cel.setTime(dt);
        SimpleDateFormat smpl = new SimpleDateFormat();
        bld.append(smpl.format(cel.getTime()));
        bld.append("<br/>");
        bld.append("<b>User Name :<FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>"
                + "Sanjiv" + "</FONT></b><br/>");
            bld.append("<b>Password :<FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>"
                    + "Sanjiv" + "</FONT></b><br/>");
        bld.append("<FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>");
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
     message.setContent(bld.toString(),
                        "text/html" );
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
```

Can anyone help me

Thanks ,
Sanjiv

Comment: By the way , what facts speaks for the not using of intregrated mail api in current JDK?

Answer (score 0):

I compared your source code with my working code at work and I couldn't see any difference.
When I looked up at the Internet I found a german [guide](http://www.joller-voss.ch/java/notes/javamail/JavaMail-Praxis.pdf) using JavaMail. According this book try this:

Use `message.setContent(bld.toString());` instead of `message.setContent(bld.toString(),"text/html" );`.

In case it wouldn't have been helped try [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0321.html) . Then it doesn't work again, check your properties from your server. Those have also an effect receiving an email in the correct format.

Comment: Yes i used like message.setContent(bld.toString(),"text/html" ); then also it is not working ,

if i run the above program normal java mail content displaying fine and if i am calling that through xhtml say send mail then only content is not displaying properly

Comment: Did you mean 'html' or 'xhtml'?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "displaying plain"?  Is it displaying all the html markup?  Or is it displaying plain text with no markup?  If the latter, the problem is with your mail server or mail reader, one of which is converting the html text to plain text.

Comment: i am  getting mail like this:

<h2>New User Request for <FONT style='color:#4649FE;'> TALON</FONT></h1><br/><b>Requested By :<FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>Y.Sanjeeva Reddygggggggggg</FONT></b><br/><b>Requested on :8/20/12 6:01 PM<br/><b>User Name :<FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>Sanjiv</FONT></b><br/><b>Password :<FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>Sanjiv</FONT></b><br/><FONT style='color:#4649FE;'>

Comment: i am setting subject message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!"); but in mail the subject comming empty i..e , no subject , and to address is comming undisclosed ids

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  Try adding message.saveChanges() before Transport.send(message).

Comment: i am using message.saveChanges() Before Transport.send(message)  :( But Not working , actually if i send Mail through java like MailClass mailClass = new MailClass();  mailClass.sendMails();  it is working fine,when i use the same method through .xhtml page like <h:commandButton action="#{MailClass.sendMails}" content is not displaying and subject is also comming empty

Comment: I have no idea.  The JavaMail FAQ has some debugging tips; try them.